# Change dbfit default date format

Tags: java, oracle, testing, dbfit

Is anyone know how to change default dateformat in DBFit/Fitnesse?
When I execute 
alter session set nls_date_format='ddmmyyyy';
and then try to insert some date in this format it gets me unparsable date exception.

I've read documentation but there is nothing about it. I also searched over forums and didn't find nothing.

Thank in advance
Przemek Woźniak